# SQL - Select 1 Field but not included with another field in another table

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have two tables and each of them have 1 field :

```
A : 01 , 02 , 03 , 04

B : 02 , 03
```

The result what i want is :

```
C : 01 , 04
```

This is my code :

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select kode_so from sales_order 
where kode_so not exists(select kode_so from budget_cost 
where kode_bc = '" & nomorso_tb.SelectedValue & "')", Conn)
```

The result is empty. How is it ? I'm using Microsoft Access as my database engine

Comment: Should you using `not in` instead of `not exists`?

Comment: I have tried that. But the result is showing all of them

Answer (score 1):

Simple ways to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM [A] 
WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT * FROM [B])
```

Or using a left join:

```
SELECT * FROM [A]  
LEFT JOIN [B] 
ON [A].id = [B].id
WHERE [B].id IS NULL
```